# Class method calling other class method without include/require?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have no clue how to phrase this question in a search engine.

I'm a bit confuse how classes use other class's methods without include/require. I've seen this in PHP a couple of time now. Coming from C++ background, I had to include everything in order to use it, so it's a bit confusing.

But ok here we go:

Say i have `improve_db_connection.php`:

```
class improve_db_connection
{

    protected $_connection;

    public function __construct($host, $user, $pwd, $db)
    {
        $this->_connection = @new mysqli($host, $user, $pwd, $db);
        if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
            throw new RuntimeException('Cannot access database: ' .
                mysqli_connect_error());
        }
    }

    public function getResultSet($sql)
    {
        $results = new Pos_MysqlImprovedResult($sql, $this->_connection);
        return $results;
    }
}
```

The `new Pos_MysqlImprovedResult` is an instance of `Pos_MysqlImprovedResult` class, not improve_db_connection. Without declaring the `include` function to include the class `Pos_MysqlImproveResult`, the `improve_db_connection.php` file just knows where the class is.

Is it because the `Pos_MysqlImproveResult.php` is in the same directory as `improve_db_connection.php`?

It's the same thing with Zend Framework. But the files are in subdirectories and such. I have a class in `application/modules/SF/models` that uses another class function that is in `application/modules/SF/models/resources`. Is it because the Zend naming convention of these classes that Zend just parse through these files and add it into the php's `__autoload`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend Framework uses Zend_Loader to automatically load classes when you reference them, as long as it can find them in a logical place.

I assume you are running a Zend Application based script, which automatically configures the Autoloader for you and does all the hard work. As your files are located in their logical folders, and the classes have the ZF convention names, ZF will find them and load them when you reference them.

More information is at the ZF manual:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.html
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.html

Comment: And if it's not a Zend application, then it can still use an autoloader that will be defined somewhere in one of the script files, and can be read to determine what paths it checks before including any necessary files.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Valorin's explanation, there's a magic method in PHP that attempts to lookup class definitions when it can't find the class definition. For a detailed explanation, go here:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

The gist of this is:

```
function __autoload ($class_name) {
    // write your logic to find the class name

    // iterate over the available paths
    foreach(explode(PATH_SEPARATOR, get_include_path()) as $path) {
        // create a local variable representing the file path to the would be include file
        $file = implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, array(
            $path, "{$class_name}.class.inc",
        ));

        // If the file doesn't exist, continue, avoiding further processing
        if (!file_exists($file)) { continue; }

        // require the file, and return to avoid further processing
        require_once $file;
        return;
    }
}

// provided there's a foo.class.inc file in one of your paths ...
$Foo = new Foo;
```